# Rusty Bulkhead Repair

Tags: repair

My bulkhead has rusted and I would like to know the easiest way to remove this rust and prevent further rust. It is a large area and sanding would be very tedious.

Comment: What sort of bulkhead? I think a picture is necessary here.

Comment: Assuming you mean bulkhead doors covering a basement door well: Repair them the same way you would any other outdoor metal such as a car. If serious rust, wire-brush the affected areas to remove all existing rust, use a fiberglass/epoxy such as bondo to fill any pits and holes, sand that flat with the surrounding metal, repaint. If it's just surface rust, you may be able to get by with wire brush, rust-neutralizing primer, and paint. Motors make all of this easier. Wear a dust mask.